# While Loop to change the name of partition table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I want to change the name of the partitioned table using a while loop.

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists dowhile$$
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE v1<10 DO
    SET @pp=concat('p',v1);
    select @pp;
    SET v1 = v1 + 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

#OUTPUT
p0
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
p6
p7
p8
p9
```

In this script, it prints the correct name of the partition but when I want to use the variable as the name of partition by changing the query below, error says Error in SQL syntax near the variable.

```
select count(*) from KJ.MAIN_TABLE partition(@pp);
```

Comment: the name of a partition is an *identifier* in SQL, just like the name of a table is an *identifier*.  Identifiers must be included in the SQL text. Identifiers cannot be supplied as *values* in a SQL statement.  (`@pp` is a user-defined value that contains a *value* ).  To get values incorporated into SQL text, we could produce the SQL text as a string, and then execute that string as dynamic SQL, with  PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE .  Reference:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html

Comment: See the example in the MySQL Reference manual  "Here is an additional example that demonstrates how to choose the table on which to perform a query at runtime, "  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Nice point @spencer7593, got it.

Comment: The "solution" should be posted as an answer, not as an edit to the question. That's the normative protocol for StackOverflow ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

By using the Prepare, Execute, and Deallocate. I've got the right syntax

```
SET @query=concat('select count(*) from KJ.MAIN_TABLE partition(',@pp,')');
prepare stmt1 from @query;
execute stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```